# how do I set an int to the scroll wheel data in unity

Tags: unity, c#

i need to set an int to data from the scroll wheel so I can have the script use this int to display an item attached to a number from that int. i'm using c#[image]

i set up my scroll wheel input, what am i doing wrong?

here is the script;

```
  counter = Mathf.RoundToInt(Input.GetAxis("ScrollWheel"));

    Items.text = counter.ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you use `RoundToInt`? I don't have experience with the ScrollWheel, but from having played with `GetAxis` it returns a value between `0` and `1`, which `RoundToInt` will always convert to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mathf.RoundToInt()` is not a conversion method, you must use a technique called [casts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwju2Y_9wK_gAhVBOK0KHSzgD8EQFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fcsharp%2Fprogramming-guide%2Ftypes%2Fcasting-and-type-conversions&usg=AOvVaw2laqP_C3r-pmDPq1naA4hV).

Try converting from float to int:

```
int scrollWheel = (int) Input.GetAxis("ScrollWheel");
```

Tell me if it works.

---

To explain, by putting `int` at the start of the line the next word becomes a new `int` or integer. We then get the value of `Input.GetAxis("ScrollWheel")`, and use `(int)` to convert it from `float` to `int` so the types are compatible.

The reason `Mathf.RoundToInt()` will not work properly is because **it ROUNDS the number to the nearest integer, as a math term, NOT the programming term.** (see [Integers - Math Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi25_6qwK_gAhVMgK0KHaX7DsIQFjABegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathsisfun.com%2Fdefinitions%2Finteger.html&usg=AOvVaw0l29nVVfKTo9UA8qxD0YIV)) For example, if you have a number that is 0.5 and used RoundToInt(), it returns 1 (the closest integer.)

What you're looking for is a way to **CONVERT** from float to int. The above code is how to do so.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this solves a problem with using `Mathf.RoundToInt()`?

Comment: @DMGregory RoundToInt is a math method, not a conversion method. I made edits.